# Vim - changing to normal mode is slow on large PHP files with syntax highlighting enabled

Tags: php, performance, vim, syntax-highlighting

When I'm using Vim 7.3 to edit a large PHP file (2000 lines), if I switch from insert mode to normal mode there is a delay of about 1-2 seconds.

It is quite frustrating when I need to make some quick edits.

On smaller files (300 lines) there is no delay. The reverse (normal mode to insert mode) there is also no delay.

The issue is related to syntax highlighting, because if I turn syntax highlighting off, the problem goes away.

```
:syntax off
```

Some things I have tried to no avail:

- turning folding off
- turning matchparen plugin off
- turning all custom plugins off
- using "largefile" plugin

Note, other than this insert-to-normal mode switching issue, nothing else about the syntax highlighting appears slow for me when editing large files. I.e. typing text in insert mode performs fine, completion works fine, etc.

This makes me think that it is something that can be fixed.

I have tested this in gVim and console vim (under cygwin) on Windows XP.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Or is anyone else able to reproduce this problem? I have googled, but can't see anyone else with this same issue which is weird.

***UPDATE***: I think it may be related only to PHP syntax highlighting. I just tried coffeescript and javascript files with 2000+ lines and did not have any issues with them.

Comment: If you hold down `j` in normal mode for a while and then let go does it continue to scroll down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen the issue you're describing, but the `InsertLeave` event would be one place to start looking.  Check your color scheme (and any other plugins) to see if there's an `InsertLeave` autocommand.  On my own system the 'lettuce.vim' colorscheme file has a handful of those; it's conceivable they're expensive, or possibly even triggering some kind of recursive processing (just thinking out loud).

**Edit**  You can check to see what autocommands are associated with a given event by doing `:au {EventName}`, e.g. `:au InsertLeave`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I did have some InsertLeave autocommands - I set some up ages ago based on this page (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text) - ironically, this was fixing another performance related issue with PHP and Vim.  It didn't click because I thought I had tested with folding off, but maybe those autocommands were still running regardless. I think it's just better to not use the php syntax folding methods (i.e. fold classes/functions) - it's just way too slow on large files. Sticking to indent-based folding for now. Cheers

Comment: I finally went looking for the reason why PHP classes above about 200lines get incredibly slow.  Turns out it was foldmethod=syntax for me. The biggest problem was at class scope, where the keyword complete would take 5s to appear.  Inside a method, a little faster, but almost unusable at the top of the class definition. Outside the class, like up in the includes, no performance problem whatsoever.  Switch to `foldmethod=indent` fixes it (and I don't really use folding much anyway)

Comment: I had the same issue with markdown files. Fixed it perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this setting in your .vimrc file.

set ttimeoutlen=0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and came up with the plugin

https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold

that updates the folds in your currently edited buffer by your preferred foldmethod when saving the buffer, and keeps them as is otherwise (by keeping the foldmethod set to  manual).